# how to set a persian font to be same in all browsers

Tags: css

Hello friends my website has two languages 1. English 2. Persian.

I have tried some fonts for my Persian language, but there is a big difference in display of

all browsers. Now in every browser my website is looking different in chrome its showing

different in fire fox different and same difference in explorer and opera.

These difference has created problems for me in one browser the fonts are big and in second

one the font is small, so it has created graphic problems for me.

How can i used a Persian font to be look same for all browsers.

```
Here is my CSS Code:


body
{
    background:#000000;
    font-family:"Calibri";
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you use the "yahoo reset" ?

Comment: what is that i have not tried yet first time hear its name

Comment: try googling for it ;)

Comment: its a rest css file, provided by Yahoo. However there are many resest CSS file available like. you can also use `normalize.css` this is modern CSS reset file.

Comment: I have included the normalize.css in my header of page the fire fox and explorer looking same but no changes in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not all platforms have "Calibri" font.
2. Calibri font may not have Farsi/Arabic letters (browsers will try to find substitution by some other Arabic font of their choice).
3. If you want predictable results then you should choose font that has such letters
4. You should explicitly define font size as different browsers may have different opinions on default font size.

Try this for example:

```
body
{
    background:#000000;
    font-family:"Arabic Typesetting", serif;
    font-size:12pt;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Not all platforms have "Arabic Typesetting" font.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela True, but that's what font list is for. It should contain desirable font family names from target platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The Calibri font does not contain Arabic letters, so with your style sheet, you get the Persian text in each browser’s default font. On systems that have Calibri installed, this causes a stylistic mismatch, because letters in Calibri are rather small (relative to the font size).

The only way to make the text rendered in the same font in all browsers (to the extent that it is possible) is to use a downloadable font, via `@font-face`. A simple way to get started is to use [Google Fonts: Early Access](http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess), where you can find several fonts that contain the characters you’ll need. Example of use:

```
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/scheherazade.css);
body { font-family: 'Scheherazade', serif; }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also create font webkit using the following site

[Convert Fonts](http://convertfonts.com/)

[Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

It will provide you a zip consiting of 5 files. It will be having following extension:-

1> .eot

2> .svg

3> .ttf

4> .woff

5> .css

Now, look at .css and specify you webkit-font url path in its url

eg:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css" >
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Sri-TSCRegular';
    src: url('sri-tsc-webfont.eot');
    src: url('sri-tsc-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('sri-tsc-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('sri-tsc-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('sri-tsc-webfont.svg#Sri-TSCRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
    body { font-family: "Sri-TSCRegular", serif }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     This is Sri-TSCRegular.
    </body>
    </html>
```